# Android Background Notification - Tap not working

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4

I have an Ionic app and a .NET backend and I'm trying to send push notifications through the Firebase Admin SDK (v1.9.0), like this:

```
public void SendToOneDeviceAsync(string registrationToken, PushNotificationMessage notificationMessage)
{
    var firebaseMessage = BuildMessage(registrationToken, notificationMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(firebaseMessage);
}
```

And the message is built like this:

```
if((!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationMessage.Title) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationMessage.Body))
                || (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationMessage.Title) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationMessage.Body)))
{
    throw new BusinessException(BusinessExceptionCodes.InvalidNotification, BusinessExceptionResources.InvalidNotification);
}

var firebaseMessage = new Message();
firebaseMessage.Token = registrationToken;

// data notification vs normal notification
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationMessage.Title) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notificationMessage.Body))
{
    if(notificationMessage.Data == null || notificationMessage.Data.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new BusinessException(BusinessExceptionCodes.InvalidNotification, BusinessExceptionResources.InvalidNotification);
    }
}
else
{
    firebaseMessage.Notification = new Notification
    {
        Title = notificationMessage.Title,
        Body = notificationMessage.Body
    };
}

firebaseMessage.Data = notificationMessage.Data;

firebaseMessage.Android = new AndroidConfig
{
    Notification = new AndroidNotification
    {
        ClickAction = "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
    }
};
```

It worked before but it's not working anymore. I've checked for updates of the Admin SDK and there's none. The notification is received, but when I tap on it, it doesn't open the app. The plugin I'm using for Ionic is [FirebaseX](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex).

Funny thing is, if I send a notification through POSTMAN, I receive it and when tapped it opens the app. Am I missing something? Is there an easy way to further debug this?

Thanks in advance.